# Using u substitution properly in integration

Tags: calculus

I would like to use the substitution $u=\cos(\frac23x)$ in the following integral:$$\int(1-\cos^2(\frac23x))\cos^4(\frac23x)\sin(\frac23x)dx$$ This gets me: $$\int-\frac32(1-u^2)u^4du$$I can pull the constant out of the integral, integrate, and undo my substitution giving me a final answer of: $$-\frac32(\frac{\cos^5(\frac23x)}{5}-\frac{\cos^7(\frac23x)}{7})$$ Is this correct? My main uncertainty is about getting a $-\frac32$ in my problem after the $u$-substitution. My first instinct was to make that a $\frac23x$, but I think this is really the correct answer. Is it?
Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Let $u=\cos\left(\frac {2x}3\right)$. Thus$$\mathrm du=-\frac 23\sin\left(\frac {2x}3\right)\,\mathrm dx$$Or, isolating the sine function$$\sin\left(\frac {2x}3\right)\,\mathrm dx=-\frac 32\,\mathrm du$$